# Right configuration of two separate login forms in one application via Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have two different users in my web app: client and translator. I created two different HttpSecurity configuration for this. I have super class for both configurations:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ua.translate"})
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customAccessDeniedHandler")
    AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web){
        web 
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(new String[]{"/resources/**"});
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,@Qualifier("detailsService") UserDetailsService uds) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(uds)
            .passwordEncoder(bcryptEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(@Qualifier("detailsService") UserDetailsService uds) {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", uds, tokenRepository);
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }


    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler 
                savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

               SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler auth 
                    = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        auth.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");
        return auth;
    }   


}
```

There are two different configurations for different users:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfigGlobal{


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class AppSecurityConfigTranslator extends AppSecurityConfig{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/translator/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/translator/registration*","/bulbular*").anonymous()
                    .antMatchers("/translator/index","/translator/login*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/translator/**").hasRole("TRANSLATOR")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/translator/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
                    .failureUrl("/translator/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .and()
                        .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                                .logoutUrl("/translator/logout")
                                .logoutSuccessUrl("/translator/login?logout")
                .and()
                    .rememberMe().tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AppSecurityConfigClient extends AppSecurityConfig{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http    
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/client/registration*","/bulbular*").anonymous()
                    .antMatchers("/client/**").hasRole("CLIENT")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/index","/translators","/orders","/client/login*").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/client/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
                    .failureUrl("/client/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .and()
                        .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                                .logoutUrl("/client/logout")
                                .logoutSuccessUrl("/client/login?logout")
                .and()
                    .rememberMe().tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when user with ROLE_CLIENT logged out, he is redirected to ../client/login and no message about successful logging out not displayed.

But when user with ROLE_TRANSLATOR logged out, he is redirected to ../translator/login?logout and message is showed, so there is no problem.

I don't understand cause of this problem, help me, please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found cause of this problem! In my configuration for client I has:

```
 .antMatchers("/client/registration*","/bulbular*").anonymous()
                    .antMatchers("/client/**").hasRole("CLIENT")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/index","/translators","/orders","/client/login*").permitAll()
```

but one rule for order of andMatchers(..) in configuration is: the most strict andMatchers must be last.

I changed order:

```
.antMatchers("/client/registration*","/bulbular*").anonymous()
                    .antMatchers("/index","/translators","/orders","/client/login*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/client/**").hasRole("CLIENT")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

And problem is solved!)